# Do any humanoid species in Star Wars have shorter average lifespans than Humans?

Tags: star-wars

It seems like there are a lot of **humanoid** species in Star Wars with longer-than-human average lifespans, but I can't think of any **humanoid** species that were called out as having shorter lives.

Were there any bipedal, sentient species in Star Wars with shorter average lifespans than Humans?

As usual for me, I don't care about Disney's new canon vs. "Legends". It's all Star Wars to me, but feel free to answer in whatever scope you prefer.

Comment: do clones count? By definition, they have accelerated maturation rates and thus age faster

Comment: relative to earth life 'a long time ago' or compared to modern earth life? It's possible there may not even have been human life as we know it in this galaxy at the time of Star Wars ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell I'd say that _all_ stormtroopers have an average shorter lifespan than ...umm... other humans :)

Comment: "aren't you a little short for a stormtrooper?" could take on a new meaning

Comment: LOL!  Dating could be problematic.  "So what do you do for a living?" "I'm a stormtrooper." "Umm, yeah, I'm actually looking for a _long_ term relationship..."

Comment: I guarantee many species were. I would assume that frogs and snakes aren't much more long lived than their earth counterparts, for instance, but I also suspect you're asking about sentient/humanoid species.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[There is a table of all the lifespan information provided in the Ultimate Alien Anthology.](https://roqoodepot.com/articles/ultimate-alien-anthology-lifespans/)

Humans are not on this list, but *The Essential Guide To Alien Species* lists them as having an average lifespan of 120 standard years. Using that as a comparison, we can actually see that a lot of the species on that list do in fact have lower lifespans than those of humans, but this is most likely due to differences in levels of medical technology rather than any natural process.

Of particular note are:

Adarian  - 65
Advozse  - 55
Balosar - 65 (The guy who tried to sell Obi-Wan death sticks in AotC is one of these)
Cerean - 65 (The member of the Jedi Council with the elongated cranium is one of these)
Charon - 65
Colicoid - 65
Em'liy - 65
**Ewok** - 60
**Geonosian** - 65
**Gungan** - 65
**Jawa** - 65
Menahuun - 55
Nikto - 65
Nuknog - 65
Ranat - 55
Squib - 65
Talz - 53
Tiss'shar - 65
and Trandoshan - 60

Which all have average lifespans of below 70. The Talz are currently the losers at a measly 53 years.

Also, in case anybody is interested, here is a list of all the species that have average lifespans in the multiple hundreds, well exceeding that of humans:

Abyssin - 300
Anzat - 950
Celegian - 250
Chevin - 256
Draethos - 780
Feeorin - 400
**Hutt** - 925
Neti - 4,000
Shi'ido - 500
Tchuukthai - 300
**Wookiee** - 400

The Neti are clearly ahead by a considerable margin, with the Anzats and the Hutts getting pretty close to 1,000.

Yoda lived to be 900 years of age, but as he and the other known members of his species were Jedi, we do not know the lifespan of the general species, since force users live considerably longer than the average.

Note: Each of the ages presented in the given lists are the point at which those species are considered "Venerable", meaning that anybody past that point is considered to have reached a great age. For Earth humans that point is around 80, which is roughly the average lifespan in the developed world in 2016. For Star Wars humans, that point is apparently around 120.

Note 2: Species labelled in bold are those that should be easily recognisable to most people who have watched the Star Wars movies.

Note 3: There are also non-humanoid species in these lists, but in the interests of a complete answer I included them anyway. Most of the species listed here are humanoid, and all are sentient.

Answer (score 1):

Devlikks have an average lifespand of 9-10 years https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Devlikk/Legends

Comment: Hi there. That link is potentially useful, but just in case it ever rots (you never know!), please [edit] in the relevant information confirming that number :)

Comment: Very nice. Didn't know about "Wan Sandage", gonna have to look out for him next time I watch Phantom Menace. Not sure if he actually has any screentime, but it's a cool bit of lore nonetheless.